# Reporting Project Management

Tags: reporting-services, ssis, powerbi

I have a question for BI/Reporting Analyst regarding Project Management.

This maybe a difficult question to answer, but I just need to get an idea of what is expected. To help with the question lets say we are working with customer relationship data(lets says Microsoft Dynamics), comms data, shop data and/or financial transactions.

I understand that the time it takes to create a report from scratch i.e. Gathering requirements -> maybe needing to setup a ETL package -> writing the SQL for the dataset to making the report on a reporting platform lets say SSRS varies based on the complexity.

I wanted to know roughly what sort of time scales are we expecting for such a project from BI/Reporting Analyst point of view.

Also, whether Analyst's work on one project at a time or do split their time between two maybe three project at time. I don't mean slight changes or incremental changes to existing reports. I mean working multiple projects starting from scratch.

If Reporting Analyst are working on multiple projects how does this affect the time it takes as opposed to the time it takes to build a report while working on one project at time.

What I want to learn from this question is what is expected from Analyst in terms of time it takes to delivery reports, and whether they are expected to work on multiple projects at the same time.

Thanks a lot for your responses in advance. Your responses will help me.
Sorry if you feel this question is pointless or if I have not been able clearly write exactly what it is I want to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question isn't pointless, but I found it a little hard to follow.  But here's what I would recommend:

Using experienced Analysts who are current employees as a condition, yes - they do work on multiple projects at once typically in a specific business area like Operations. Time impacts are based on how many projects at once.  You should ask the manager of your BI Analysis group how many projects they typically handle at once.  For discussion, let's say 3.  No one's work is evenly split, but you can roughly estimate by assuming 1/3 of the Analyst's time is on your project. So do the math based on 33% of an FTE (Full Time Equivalency or 1 full time employee) with an average work month of 176 hours (8 per day x 22 work days) and you get 59 hours rounded up.

Given the data examples, I think that an ETL tool would help the process.  For more information you can read this blog post on [ETL tools](http://blog.panoply.io/11-great-etl-tools-and-the-case-for-saying-no-to-etl) and using ELT instead. Depending on the software, someone from your data team will likely install it; the Analyst would be setting up data flows and queries.  Time varies, but for a specific use likely 30-40 hours. Once the application is configured, producing the reports is quick but allow time to format them into presentation quality (dreaded PowerPoint, or a spreadsheet.) I'd say that's 2-3 times the minutes required to run the query and produce the report.  You could see what time current reports take your company and base it off of that, or use a round number like 60 or 90 minutes per report. I prefer to use actual data.

So to sum up, 40 hours to configure the ETL tool, 90 minutes per report with 1/3 of an FTE.  Let's say you need 5 reports:
(40 + (90 x 5)) = 490 hours at 59 hours per week = 8 1/2 weeks rounded up.